# How to display local (non-external) symbols in a C-program using `nm` on macOS?

Tags: c, macos, x86, symbols, nm

I want to display local (non-external) symbols in a C-program using `nm` on macOS.

I've read the `man nm`, and it essentially gives me the following options for displaying symbol information:

```
nm -m (Mach-O symbols)
nm -g (external symbols)
nm -a (all symbols)
```

However, for the **main.c** program below, I'd expect `nm -a` to also output `foo`, since it's defined as a local symbol (internal linkage) by using the `static` keyword:

```
nm -a main
0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
0000000100000f60 T _bar
0000000100000f30 T _main
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

But, `foo` is not listed among the symbols. How can I make `nm` list all symbols (including local ones)?

**main.c** (compiled as `clang main.c -o main`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("main");
}

static void foo() {
    printf("foo");
}

extern void bar() {
    printf("baz");
}
```

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`  When compiling, always enable the warnings.  This statement will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Also, the compiler will output a warning message about `foo` being defined but not used.  (typically, unused items are eliminated by the compiler)

Comment: How do you enable all warnings? `-W`?

Comment: Usually, `-W` disables all warnings.  Suggest reading: [clang compiler options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) especially the chapter: `Command Line Options`  Per the manual, the option: `-Weverything`  Enables all diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not finding it because it isn't there -- look at the disassembly (`objdump -d`).

Compilers routinely eliminate unused static functions even at -O0. To keep the foo function you can try making it both used and nontrivial (so it doesn't get inlined).

E.g., for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("main");
}

static void foo() {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    printf("foo");
}

extern void bar() {
    printf("baz");
    foo();
}
```

I get:

```
0000000000000000 T bar
0000000000000000 t foo
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
```

with clang on Linux. You should get similar results on MacOS.

Comment: Thanks, don't you also get `__mh_execute_header` and `dyld_stub_binder` in the output?

Comment: Also, why are yours symbols not prefixed with `_`, e.g. `_bar`?

Comment: @Shuzheng That's all MacOS-specific stuff. (Underscore prefixes are common elsewhere too, but it's a rather obsolete convention that started with the original Unix to avoid name clashes with then pre-existing assembly routines. Linux doesn't do that.)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question 

Answer (score 1):

To add up on @PSkocik excellent answer you can ensure the function will be emitted in the final binary with:

```
static void foo() __attribute__((used));

static void foo() {
    printf("foo");
}
```

Comment: Awesome, is `__attribute__((used))` standard C, or is it specific to `clang`?

Comment: @Shuzheng it's a feature of `clang` and `gcc` (GNU C), but not standard C.